# Print alpha-numeric characters using regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I am new to regular expression.

I need to print all combination  8 characters (alphanumeric) which follow the below pattern.

- First character must be alphabetic
- Second characters must be numeric
- Must not have 3 consecutive numeric characters
- Must not have 4 consecutive alphabetic characters

Comment: How is regex involved?

Comment: Its an options to use regex

Comment: Regular expressions are used to define a syntax. The match and substitute operators check if a string matches a syntax pattern defined using a regex. I am unaware of any tools that use a regex pattern to generate strings.

Comment: `all combination 8 characters (alphanumeric)` is about `62**8`. To print all of this, you'll use tons of paper.

Comment: Yes all combination will generate enormous number. My goal is to generate all of them and store in database. But for now to just need print 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are used to define a syntax. The match and substitute operators check if a string matches a syntax pattern defined using a regex. I am unaware of any tools that use a regex pattern to generate strings.

---

When you have an arbitrary number of nested loops, you want [Algorithm::Loops](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm::Loops)'s `NestedLoops`. In your case, there's a fixed number of loops, but there are so many that `NestedLoops` comes in useful anyway.

[I'm assuming you're only interested in the letters and numbers in ASCII.]

Naïve (generates all sequences, and filters out the unwanted ones):

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my @syms = ('A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9');

my $iter = NestedLoops([ (\@syms) x 8 ]);

while (my @s = $iter->()) {
   my $s = join('', @s);
   next if $s !~ /^[a-zA-Z][0-9]/;
   next if $s =~ /[a-zA-Z]{4}|[0-9]{3}/;
   say $s;
}
```

Mostly naïve (generates all sequences except obviously bad ones, and filters out the unwanted ones):

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my @letters = ('A'..'Z', 'a'..'z');
my @digits  = ('0'..'9');
my @syms    = (@letters, @digits);

my $iter = NestedLoops([
   \@letters,
   \@digits,
   (\@syms) x 6,
]);

while (my @s = $iter->()) {
   my $s = join('', @s);
   next if $s =~ /[a-zA-Z]{4}|[0-9]{3}/;
   say $s;
}
```

But that still generates a lot of strings that need to be thrown away. The following only generates the string we want. It does that by generating the patterns that will produce desirable strings (`LDLLLDLL`, `LDLLLDLD`, `LDLLLDDL`, `LDLLDLLL`, ...), then builds strings from those patterns.

Efficient algorithm (which doesn't mean the implementation is efficient):

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my @letters = ('A'..'Z', 'a'..'z');
my @digits  = ('0'..'9');

sub make_pat_gen_iter {
   my $raw_pat_gen_iter = NestedLoops([
      ['L'],
      ['D'],
      (['L','D']) x 6,
   ]);

   return sub {
      while (1) {
         my @pat = $raw_pat_gen_iter->();
         return () if !@pat;

         my $pat = join('', @pat);
         next if $pat =~ /L{4}|D{3}/;

         return @pat;
      }
   };
}

sub make_gen_iter {
   my $pat_gen_iter = make_pat_gen_iter();
   my @pat;

   my $gen_sub_iter;

   return sub {
      return () if !$pat_gen_iter;

      while (1) {
         if (!$gen_sub_iter) {
            @pat = $pat_gen_iter->();
            if (!@pat) {
               $pat_gen_iter = undef;
               return ();
            }

            $gen_sub_iter = NestedLoops([
               map { $_ eq 'L' ? \@letters : \@digits } @pat
            ]);
         }

         my @s = $gen_sub_iter->();
         if (!@s) {
            $gen_sub_iter = undef;
            next;
         }

         return join('', @s);
      }
   };
}

my $gen_iter = make_gen_iter();

while (defined( my $s = $gen_iter->() )) {
   say $s;
}
```

For fun, the following is the complete result of the pattern iterator:

```
LDLLLDLL    LDLLLDLD    LDLLLDDL    LDLLDLLL    LDLLDLLD
LDLLDLDL    LDLLDLDD    LDLLDDLL    LDLLDDLD    LDLDLLLD
LDLDLLDL    LDLDLLDD    LDLDLDLL    LDLDLDLD    LDLDLDDL
LDLDDLLL    LDLDDLLD    LDLDDLDL    LDLDDLDD    LDDLLLDL
LDDLLLDD    LDDLLDLL    LDDLLDLD    LDDLLDDL    LDDLDLLL
LDDLDLLD    LDDLDLDL    LDDLDLDD    LDDLDDLL    LDDLDDLD
```

Comment: I am getting the below outputCan't locate Algorithm/Loops.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Algorithm::Loops module) (@INC contains: 
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/l
ib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at main.pl line 4.                                                             
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at main.pl line 4.

Comment: Do you have the module installed?

Comment: installed, now getting Can't locate object method "say" via package "A0AAA0AA" (perhaps you forgot to load "A0AAA0AA"?) at sr.pl line 62.

Comment: I got it working thnx mate! it will help me to progress in my project

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings; use feature qw( say );`. You could also switch to using `print` instead. (But still add `use strict; use warnings;` if you do.)

Comment: I am working on a project with enormous amount of data. This code is very crucial part of project for getting uniq id. Since I need to store this in database, i have a question. Can the script be modifed in such a way that it generates 1 million and exit(). The last record generated alphanumeric is stored. When we call the script again give the last generated as argument and script should continue to generate next 1 million

Comment: First part yes. Second part no

Comment: I tried few things like generating all the code, storing and then populating the table in increment of 1 million if the unused uniq id < 10%. But its bit complicated. Could you suggest something smarter?

Comment: I personally would write a specialized version of NestedLoops.

Answer (score 0):

You can check each pattern.
Let's name the string **$str**. Generate **$str** from "00000000" to "zzzzzzzz" and use following **if** clause to pick up strings that match the patterns.

```
if ($str =~ /^[A-Za-z][0-9]/        // pattern 1 and 2
  && $str !~ /[0-9]{3}/             // pattern 3
  && $str !~ /[A-Za-z]{4}/)         // pattern 4
```